# Adding double quotes while making a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code

```
import csv
with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
```

The output I get:

```
SN, Name, Contribution
1, Linus Torvalds, Linux Kernel
```

The output I want:

```
SN, Name, Contribution
1, Linus Torvalds, "Linux Kernel"
```

So, I tried

```
writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "\"Linux Kernel\""])
```

But that just makes it into:

```
1, Linus Torvalds, ""Linux Kernel""
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code with python 3, not sure how I can get it to output the word with double quotes

Comment: Try '"Linus Torvalds"', '"Linux Kernel"'

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha tried is end up looking like 1, """"Linus Torvalds"""', ""'"Linux Kernel"'""

Comment: you tried one quote+double quote?

Comment: yea the code was: writer.writerow([1, '"Linus Torvalds"', '"Linux Kernel"'])

Answer (score 7):

You can control the level of quoting with quoting argument to csv.writer. If you just want to quote all values, use *csv.QUOTE_ALL*.

Quoting levels:

**csv.QUOTE_ALL**
Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.

**csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC**
Instructs writer objects to quote all non-numeric fields.
Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.

**csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL** (Default)
Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the characters in lineterminator.

**csv.QUOTE_NONE**
Instructs writer objects to never quote fields.

**Example:**

```python
import csv

with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
```

**Output:**

```
"SN","Name","Contribution"
1,"Linus Torvalds","Linux Kernel"
```

Notice in the output that all the strings are quoted and the number is not.

If use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` then output is the following. None of the strings have new line or escape characters so no quotes are required.

```
SN,Name,Contribution
1,Linus Torvalds,Linux Kernel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file,quotechar = "'")
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds",'"Linux Kernel"' ])
```

Comment: So I tried doing the way you did it but the output was `'''Linux Kernel'''` But if I ignored the forward slashes it was able to quote successfully. My input was `'"Linux Kernel"'` and the output was `"Linux Kernel"`. Thank you

Comment: Welcome. I'm editing the comment.